# How to make bigger slides with AnythingSlider (jquery plugin)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I've followed the instructions on the website of Anything slider (http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/), about customizing, but when I add width, I have slides dissapear or blank slides.

Any help will be much apprecied.

Answer (score 1):

To make the slides bigger all you have to change is the following:

```
/* this is the width of the outer container */
.anythingSlider { 
        width: 670px; /*change this value */
        height: 137px; /* change this value */
        position: relative; 
        margin: 0 auto 0; 

    } 

/* this is the width of the inner container */
    .anythingSlider .wrapper { 
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        width: 670px; /*change this value */
        overflow: hidden; 
        height: 137px; /*change this value */
        margin: 0 10px; 
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0; 
    }

/* this is the width of the slide */
    .anythingSlider ul li { 
        display: block; 
        float: left; 
        padding: 0; 
        height: 317px; /*change this value */
        width: 680px; /*change this value */
        margin: 0; 
    }
```

and that's it, that's all you have to change to make the slider have a bigger width and height.

If you've changed anything else, that'll be the problem.

If this doesn't work, post up your code so we can see the actual problem.